# Visual Studio 2022 shows git repo as "Untrusted"

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 has started showing one of my git repos as "Untrusted". What does this mean? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: If the answer by @jessehouwing does not work; I've also gotten around it by just opening VS 2022 in Administrator mode.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a new security feature in Git to prevent people from sticking things into a shared git repo to infect your PC. It may have been a bit overboard, but now we'll have to deal with it in every tool on our PCs that use Git:

### Why oh Why?

This change in Git came about due a security issue which allows parent repositories directories to override permissions of child repositories in some situations which would potentially allow execution of commands with unintended consequences. You can read more detail about the specific vulnerability here:

Git Security Issue: [CVE-2022-24765](https://github.blog/2022-04-12-git-security-vulnerability-announced/#cve-2022-24765)

### Quick Fixes

There are a number of solutions for this problem.

- `git config --global --add safe.directory <Git folder>`
- Manually adding an entry to the git config:

  ```
  [safe] 
     directory = d:/projects/path
  ```
- Developer Tools can set Safe Repo Status, click <kbd>view details</kbd> in the yellow information bar:

  [image]
- Change Folder Ownership. In the File System properties on your machine, change the owner of the directory to be your user.

[For details see here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2023/Jan/05/Fix-that-damn-Git-Unsafe-Repository#git-config-command-fix).

Comment: just opening vs2022 solved this issue though

Comment: Can you expand more on the "Developer Tools"?  How do you open that panel?  Is this an extension or built-in to VS 2022?

Comment: Built-in to vs 2022 in recent versions.

Comment: @jessehouwing can you please edit your solution to say to the user to click on "View Details" to open the "Untrusted Git repository". Thanks.

Comment: @BDisp like this?